# Monokai (Sublime text 2) theme for Resharper ( c# )

Tags: visual-studio, themes, resharper

as you may know Visual Studio doesn't offer the same degrees of freedom when it comes to Syntax Highlighting as Sublime Text 2 does (subject to opinion/bias, this is mine), however, Resharper does have some abilities when it comes to syntax highlighting to improve on Visual Studio's default highlighting.

So that being said, before I start making my own, does anyone have a Monokai - the default Sublime Text 2 theme - for Resharper?

I know I can use studiostyl.es - however those themes are for Visual Studio only, so the Monokai themes there are only roughly equivalent to the Monokai offered in ST2.

if anyone has the theme, could you paste it here?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the [theme](https://github.com/condemil/VisualMonokai) I created a while ago.

It doesn't contains ReSharper colors yet, but they can be easily added from [original dark](https://github.com/condemil/VisualMonokai/blob/master/OriginalSettingsDark.vssettings) theme included in the repository.

I edited theme files manually to support them quite easy to understand and make color changes.

Answer (score 2):

test this link .... and enjoy it !
there is a lot of sublime text monokai schemes for visual studio but this one is a fresh and clean item.
you can select your VS version and click download to get suitable version of theme file.

see bellow link :
https://studiostyl.es/schemes/monokai

Comment: Instead of linking to an external site and not even telling why it is an answer to the question is not a good answer, I think. Please, take some time and read through [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) carefully.